# decoding, little endian, uncompressed and float array

Tags: python, base64

I have **Base64** encoded data from an experiment. So what I am trying to do in stepwise is:

- Retrieve bytes from base64 encoding (Decode it)
- Convert bytes to little-endian
- Decompress bytes from (zlib)
- Convert byte array to float array

Example:

`Dn3LQ3np4kOyxQJE20kDRBRuFkScZB5ENxEzRFa+O0THMz9EOQRCRFC1QkRYeUNEwXJJROfbSUScvE5EVDtVRK5PV0TLUWNE481lRHX7ZkSBBWpE9FVyRIFdeESkoHhEnid8RI1nfUSy4YBE/C2CRGKQg0RcR4RE54uEROUAhUTBWodErKyMRNsVkkRvUpJEukWURO58lkSqRZ1E2VauRPBTwEQf9cVE9BnKRA==`

What I have tried so far

```
import os
import base64
import struct

s = 'Dn3LQ3np4kOyxQJE20kDRBRuFkScZB5ENxEzRFa+O0THMz9EOQRCRFC1QkRYeUNEwXJJROfbSUScvE5EVDtVRK5PV0TLUWNE481lRHX7ZkSBBWpE9FVyRIFdeESkoHhEnid8RI1nfUSy4YBE/C2CRGKQg0RcR4RE54uEROUAhUTBWodErKyMRNsVkkRvUpJEukWURO58lkSqRZ1E2VauRPBTwEQf9cVE9BnKRA=='
decode=base64.decodestring(s)

tmp_size=len(decode)/4
```

Now I am trying to convert these byte to little endian from here.

I want to do the next operation in **Python**.

I am trying to figure it out myself but, it is taking too much time.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you having problems? We will help with any specific questions you have, but we will not write your code for you.

Comment: If you truly do appreciate it, please _edit_ your question and add the requested information.

Comment: Thank you I will delete question for now, will try, try and try and if doesn't make sense that will come up with what I have done!

Comment: That's all I am asking for - explain what you have tried, post the code and we will see :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears your data isn't actually compressed.  Read the data as floats either in a loop using [`struct.unpack_from()`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#struct.unpack_from) or as one big structure using [`struct.unpack()`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#struct.unpack).

```py
import base64
import struct

encoded = 'Dn3LQ3np ... 9BnKRA=='

# decode the string
data = base64.standard_b64decode(encoded)

# ensure that there's enough data for 32-bit floats
assert len(data) % 4 == 0

# determine how many floats there are
count = len(data) // 4

# unpack the data as floats
result = struct.unpack('<{0}f'.format(count), # one big structure of `count` floats
                       data)                  # results returned as a tuple
```

If the data is compressed, decompress it.

```py
import zlib

decompressed = zlib.decompress(data)
```

Comment: consider using `'<%df' % count` instead of `'<' + 'f' * count`

Comment: Ah, didn't know we could use it that way.  Seems to work too.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: This is just an example, data can be compressed or uncompressed!

Answer (score 1):

> Convert bytes to little-endian

Byte ordering only applies to data types that are greater than 1 byte.  So you can't just convert a list of bytes to little-endian.  You need to understand what is in your list of bytes.

A 32-bit integer is 4 bytes;  If you have 16 bytes of data.  You could "unpack" that into 4 32-bit integers.

If the data is just ascii text the endianness doesn't matter, that's why you can read the exact same ascii text file on both big-endian and little-endian machines.

Here is an example demonstrating struct.pack and struct.unpack:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import struct
# 32-bit unsigned integer
# base 10       2,864,434,397
# base 16       0xAABBCCDD
u32 = 0xAABBCCDD
print 'u32 =', u32, '(0x%x)' % u32
# big endian    0xAA 0xBB 0xCC 0xDD
u32be = struct.pack('>I', u32)
bx = [byte for byte in struct.unpack('4B', u32be)]
print 'big endian packed', ['0x%02x' % x for x in bx]
assert bx == [0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd]
# little endian 0xDD 0xCC 0xBB 0xAA
u32le = struct.pack('<I', u32)
lx = [byte for byte in struct.unpack('4B', u32le)]
print 'little endian packed', ['0x%02x' % x for x in lx]
assert lx == [0xdd, 0xcc, 0xbb, 0xaa]
# 64-bit unsigned integer
# base 10       12,302,652,060,662,200,000
# base 16       0xAABBCCDDEEFF0011
u64 = 0xAABBCCDDEEFF0011L
print 'u64 =', u64, '(0x%x)' % u64
# big endian    0xAA 0xBB 0xCC 0xDD 0xEE 0xFF 0x00 0x11
u64be = struct.pack('>Q', u64)
bx = [byte for byte in struct.unpack('8B', u64be)]
print 'big endian packed', ['0x%02x' % x for x in bx]
assert bx == [0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff, 0x00, 0x11]
# little endian 0x11 0x00 0xFF 0xEE 0xDD 0xCC 0xBB 0xAA
u64le = struct.pack('<Q', u64)
lx = [byte for byte in struct.unpack('8B', u64le)]
print 'little endian packed', ['0x%02x' % x for x in lx]
assert lx == [0x11, 0x00, 0xff, 0xee, 0xdd, 0xcc, 0xbb, 0xaa]
```

check out the documentation for more info: http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#format-strings

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your next step will be to use `struct`.  Something like this:

```
struct.unpack("<f", decode[0:4])
```

This example will turn the first four bytes of `decode` into a float.  Check out the [struct documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) for more info on format strings, etc.